# How bump node reads images in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

When I plug an image to the "bump node" ( or "Displacement" ) Does it consider the black value as 0.0 height or the gray ones (0.5,0.5,0.5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Short Answer:

It doesn't matter at all.

## Long Answer:

Bump mapping doesn't really care whether the colour of a particular pixel is black or grey or white or even negative. What it does care about, is the **relation between that pixel and the pixels surrounding it**.

[image: compare]

The only thing that matter is the **difference between the values**. The two sets of pixels in the image above will give identical results, because the difference between black (0.0) and grey (0.5) is `0.5`, and the difference between grey and white (1.0) is also `0.5`.

As proof, here are two identical renders:

[image: proof]

## Why is it like this?

Under the hood, Blender is simply calculating the **surface normal** for each pixel. A normal is simply the direction that point on the surface is facing, irregardless of its position.

---

**Note:** None of this is true for actual displacement, only bump mapping.